# Replace "Value From Cells" in chart data labels using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I have copied  several charts from a workbook to another and I managed to change the data series with vba.

Some of the data labels of these charts, get data "**From Cells**" but this range is still referencing the the first workbook and I need to change it to reference the new sheet in the new workbook.

I am being able to get the formula that references the "From Cells".

This is the code that I have

```
Sub xtDataLabels_FromCells()
    Dim oChart As ChartObject
    Dim OldString As String, NewString As String
    Dim mySrs As Variant

    OldString = "'[Daily Report]SP'!$P$11:$P$20"
    NewString = "SP!$P$11:$P$20"

    For Each oChart In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
        For Each mySrs In oChart.Chart.SeriesCollection
            ' From a recorded macro
            'ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(7).DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange. _
                InsertChartField msoChartFieldRange, "=SP!$P$11:$P$20", 0
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

**"Value From Cells"**

[image]

Regards,
Elio Fernandes

Comment: What is "From Cells"? Named range? Literal? Where this "From Cells" is in code?

Comment: I just updated my post with a picture, refering to "Label Options -> Value From Cells"

Comment: I don't know whether this will be appropriate for you, but you can create charts which can be independent of sheet's data. You can copy and paste such charts any place you want - the data will go with it. As for you chart, you need qualify your range with sheet reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is exactly what you want. Your code loops through all series of all charts and apparently wants to use the same range for labels. This will do it:

```
Sub xtDataLabels_FromCells()
    Dim oChart As ChartObject
    Dim OldString As String, NewString As String
    Dim mySrs As Variant

    OldString = "'[Daily Report]SP'!$P$11:$P$20" ' irrelevant
    NewString = "SP!$P$11:$P$20"

    For Each oChart In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
        For Each mySrs In oChart.Chart.SeriesCollection
            ' From a recorded macro
            mySrs.DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange. _
                InsertChartField msoChartFieldRange, "=" & NewString, 0
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

If you want to do a Find & Replace of the existing chart field, I'm afraid you're out of luck. You can use VBA to *set* the chart field using `InsertChartField`, but you can't use VBA to *read* what is in an existing chart field.

Just another shortcoming of the VBA Object Model for Excel charts.

Comment: I really was hooping that I could do a Find & Replace of a chart field. Thanks Jon. I like very much your web site and I have learned a lot.